# Microsoft Graph/Azure and event subscription

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a problem with Microsoft Graph/Azure and event subscription.

Currently, I've done this :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

```
{
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "resourceData": {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.User",
        "displayName": {
            "eq": true
        },
        "givenName": {
            "eq": true
        },
        "surname": {
            "eq": true
        },
        "country": {
            "eq": true
        },
        "passwordProfile": {
            "eq": false
        }
    },
    "notificationUrl": "...",
    "resource": "users",
    "expirationDateTime": "2023-10-25T15:50:32+00:00",
    "clientState": "secretClientState"
}
```

And yet, every time I change a password, for example, it's returned to my Webhook, which I don't want. Perhaps some of you have already succeeded?

I only want to send basic changes to my webhook, such as the last name, first name and country, for example.

Here is the authorisation I gave in Azure :
[authorisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH7Wn.png)

Thanks